# Twig execute a function once instead of 3 times

Tags: twig

I was wondering if it is possible to create some sort of condition which can be used on 3 different places in a template with Twig.

Let's say I have 3 slider images with a link. A user of the template has the option to choose between a button link or a normal link via a dropdown menu. Like so (below is only the first slider):

```
 {% if theme.slide1 %}      
 <li class="animate-in f1">
    <div class="wrap">         
      <a href="{{ theme.slide1_link | t }}" class="{{ link_style }}">{{ 'Read more' | t }}</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  {% endif %}

 {% if theme.slide2 %}      
 <li class="animate-in f2">
    <div class="wrap">         
      <a href="{{ theme.slide2_link | t }}" class="{{ link_style }}">{{ 'Read more' | t }}</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
```

Normally you would do something like:

```
{% if theme.slide1_link_setting == 'Link' %} do this {% else %} do that {% endif %}
```

You have to do this 3 times if you have 3 slider images. But what if you have eg. 10 slider images?

I tried to create a function which checks if a setting is a button or normal link.

```
{% set link_style = theme.slide1_link in ['link', 'button'] ? 'normal-link': 'btn btn-custom-2 btn-sequence' %}
```

First of all the function above doesn't work. 
Second I don't know how to set the number of the slide you're in. I want something like below:

```
{% set link_style = theme.slide[numberOfSlide]_link in ['link', 'button'] ? 'normal-link': 'btn btn-custom-2 btn-sequence' %}
```

Is there anybody who can help me with this?